# Find DOM-element that occurs the most

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

A container *div.example* can have different **1st-level child** elements (*section*, *div*, *ul*, *nav*, ...). Quantity and type of those elements can vary.

I have to find the type (e.g. *div*) of the direct child that occurs the most. 
What is a simple jQuery or JavaScript solution?

jQuery 1.7.1 is available, although it should work in IE < 9 (array.filter) as well.

Edit: Thank you @Jasper, @Vega and @Robin Maben :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the children using `.children()` and log the number of `element.tagName`s you find:

```
//create object to store data
var tags = {};

//iterate through the children
$.each($('#parent').children(), function () {

    //get the type of tag we are looking-at
    var name = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

    //if we haven't logged this type of tag yet, initialize it in the `tags` object
    if (typeof tags[name] == 'undefined') {
        tags[name] = 0;
    }

    //and increment the count for this tag
    tags[name]++;
});
```

Now the `tags` object holds the number of each type of tag that occurred as a child of the `#parent` element.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRjtp/ (watch your console for the object)

Then to find the tag that occurred the most you could do this:

```
var most_used = {
        count : 0,
        tag   : ''
    };

$.each(tags, function (key, val) {
    if (val > most_used.count) {
        most_used.count = val;
        most_used.tag   = key;
    }
});
```

The `most_used` object now holds the tag used the most and how many times it was used.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRjtp/1/

Comment: Instead of `$.each($('#parent').children(), `, you can do `$('#parent').children().each(`.

Comment: @Rocket Yeah, it may seem funny, but `$.each()` is faster so why not use it? :) Here is a JSPerf to show the difference: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/7

Comment: That test is for an array, when dealing with DOM elements (jQuery selectors), `.each` is better.  http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-jquery-each

Comment: @Jasper: No, that jsperf test does really not apply to this case.

Comment: That's a decent point, but it doesn't exactly evangelize using `.each()`. `$.each()` seems to be either faster or the same speed.

Comment: @Rocket Why better? It looks like they perform the same. Thanks for bring-up that point though.

Comment: @Jasper: Darn, I was hoping `.each` would be better.  Oh well :-P

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I think a jQuery function like below should be more useful..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HraSj/6/)

```
$.fn.theMostChild = function() {
    var childs = {};
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        if (childs.hasOwnProperty(this.nodeName)) {
            childs[this.nodeName] += 1;
        } else {
            childs[this.nodeName] = 1;
        }
    });
    var maxNode = '', maxNodeCount = 0;
    for (nodeName in childs) {
        if (childs[nodeName] > maxNodeCount) {
            maxNode = nodeName;
            maxNodeCount = childs[nodeName];
        }
    }
    return $(maxNode);
}
```

And then you can,

```
$('div.example').theMostChild().css('color', 'red');
```

---

A function like below should give you the count of child elements, from which you can get the max count. See below,
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HraSj/)

```
$(function () {
    var childs = {};
    $('div.example').children().each(function () {
        if (childs.hasOwnProperty(this.nodeName)) {
            childs[this.nodeName] += 1;
        } else {
            childs[this.nodeName] = 1;
        }
    });

    for (i in childs) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + childs[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: just a quick question, in theMost() should'nt the return value be $(maxNode) instead of $(nodeName)

Comment: @Vega: Thanks so much for your answer. It is always hard to chose among two similar answers, especially if there are just 3 minutes between their posting time.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>That is not possible without some information about the expected types of child nodes.</strike>

**EDIT** : It is possible as [Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752738/jasper) pointed out that we need not know the tag names before hand. The following works in case you're looking only **within a specific set of selectors**.

```
var selectorArray = ['div', 'span', 'p',........]

var matches = $(div).children(selectorArray.join());    
var max = 0, result = [];    
$.each(selectorArray, function(i, selector){

    var l = matches.filter(selector).length;
    if(l > max){
     max = l;
     result[max] = selector;
    }

});
```

`result[max]` gives you the tag name and `max` gives you the occurrence count

Comment: `tagName` should do the trick right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName

Comment: @Jasper: Yes, you're right. Overlooked that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Robin: Thanks alot for your answer :) Do you know if older IEs have a problem with _matches.filter(selector).length_? [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#showold) says no support for Array.filter in IE6/7/8.